# Problem syncing Windows Phone with Outlook

Tags: sync, email, outlook

I am having problems syncing my Lumia 520 with Outlook. the problem started some weeks ago. I get error code 80C805E2.

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Have you tried the solutions [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2933402)?

Comment: I tried removing the account and then adding it again. It would work for sometime but the issue occurs again

Comment: Have you tried any of the **five** solutions described in the link I posted?

Comment: If there is an alternative, then I do not want to reset my phone for this. :(

Comment: Er... there are **four** alternatives in that link that don't involve resetting your phone. Once again, did you try them? Edit: in case it's not obvious, you can click on each solution to expand it and see the full instructions.

Comment: It was mentioned there that "tap the sync button several times. It may take a while until the phone syncs all the information it needs to sync". I overlooked it.

Comment: Don't know which of the 4 alternative worked! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft KB article 2933402](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2933402) lists the following possible causes for this problem:

> You may get this error if:
>
> - You bulk deleted items, such as text message threads.
> - You deleted or moved many email items over a period of time.

It goes on to suggest that the following solutions be tried in order. After each solution, try syncing your phone again before moving to the next one.

> 1. #### Disable text message backup
>
>    Try turning off the option to back up your text messages:
>
>    - On **Start**, flick left to the **App** list, tap **Settings**, swipe to **Applications**, then tap **Messaging**.
>    - Tap to toggle **Text message backup** to **Off**.
>    - If the option is available, tap to toggle **Chat backup** to **Off**.
>    - Sync your **Microsoft account** by going back to **Settings**, then tap **Email+accounts**. Tap and hold your Microsoft account, then tap **Sync**.
> 2. #### Sync the Deleted items folder
>
>    To sync your Deleted items folder or your Trash folder:
>
>    - Go to the **Inbox** for your Microsoft account.
>    - Tap the **Ellipsis** button [**…**], and then tap **Folders**.
>    - Tap **Show all folders**.
>    - Select the **Deleted items** (or **Trash**) folder. Then, tap **Sync this folder**.
>        **Note** Alternatively, select the folder you frequently moving emails to from the phone, then sync that folder.
>    - Go back to the inbox of your Microsoft account and tap the **Sync button**. If you continue to get the same error, tap the sync button several times. It may take a while until the phone syncs all the information it needs to sync.
> 3. #### Empty the Deleted items folder
>
>    To empty the Deleted items or Trash folder:
>
>    - Go to the **Inbox** of your Microsoft account.
>    - Tap the **Ellipsis** button [**…**], and then tap **Folders**.
>    - Tap **Show all folders**.
>    - Select the **Deleted items** (or **Trash**) folder to view its contents.
>    - Tap the **Ellipsis** button [**…**], and then tap **Empty folder**.
>    - Go back to the inbox of your Microsoft account and tap the **Sync button**. If you continue to get the same error, tap the sync button several times. It may take a while until the phone syncs all the information it needs to sync.
> 4. #### Reset email sync
>
>    To reset the sync option for your email:
>
>    - On **Start**, flick left to the **App** list, tap **Settings**, then tap **Email+accounts**.
>    - Tap your Microsoft account to access the settings for the account.
>    - Under **Content to sync**, *deselect* the **Email** checkbox.
>    - Tap the **Done** button.
>    - Tap your Microsoft account again to access the settings for the account.
>    - Under **Content to sync**, *reselect* the **Email** checkbox.
>    - Tap the **Done** button.
>        **Note** Following these steps will cause your email tile to become unpinned from its original location and will now be at the
>        bottom of your Start screen.
> 5. #### Reset your phone
>
>    If the steps above still didn't help, your phone may be in a bad
>      state, which means you will have to reset the phone to its original
>      factory settings and set it up again.
>
>    **Note** For more information about how to reset your phone, see the
>      Help & How to article [Reset my phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/basics/reset-my-phone).
>
>    To reset your phone, follow these steps.
>
>    - On **Start**, flick left to the **App** list and tap **Settings**.
>    - Tap **About**, then tap **Reset your phone**.
>    - Tap **Yes**, then tap **Yes** again.

Comment: I have a Lumia 640 LTE running Windows 10 Mobile Version 1703 OS build 10.0.15063.850. I suddenly lost the ability to sync email in Outlook and 4. Reset email sync worked for me after reselecting the email checkbox, but it took all day with multiple presses of the sync button after using the following Hotmail sync settings: Download new content: as items arrive;
Download email: from the last 3 months.